# Network inside k8s appears to be clogged

Tags: kubernetes, networking, rabbitmq

There is a k8s installation which hosts, beside many others, two pods: a microservice and an instance of RMQ. I can also run the microservice on my local machine, from which the microservice talks to the RMQ instance in k8s over Internet.

From the local machine, the communication to RMQ is stable, with latency of ~600ms all the time. From the pod inside k8s, latency is much smaller -- most of the time. However, every minute or so, it takes up to 20 seconds for my pod to connect to RMQ! Periodically, CreateConnection() fails altogether with the error 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'.

Where should I be looking? Unfortunately, the k8s's sysadmin is helpless, so I need to look elsewhere for help.

Answer (score 0):

So, to finalize. The problem looked like this. For every publication, a new connection was created. Under Windows it was OK, connection time was about 2 ms. Under Kubernetes, it could be much more with a chance of failure.

For long time, it was understood as a problem at the particular K8S cluster. However, for a fresh new installation, the problem reproduced, with slightly smaller delays.

So the software was rewritten to re-use an RMQ connection, which cured the problem. Why does K8S demonstrate such a behavior, remains unknown.